# Confusion about a code in swift ? #array #matrix

Tags: arrays, swift, matrix

```
struct Matrix {
  let rows: Int, columns: Int
  var grid: [Double]
  init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
     self.rows = rows
     self.columns = columns
     grid = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: rows * columns)
  }
  subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> Double {
     get {
        return grid[(row * columns) + column]
     }
     set {
        grid[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
     }
   }
  }

var m = Matrix(rows: 2, columns: 2)
m[0, 0] = 1.1
m[0, 1] = 2.1
print(m[0, 0])
```

1. My question is in get and set inside the grid what +colum means the grid is returning the value of array position in the matrix. When remove I remove the +colum from code it sets the value in the wrong position.So why there is a +column in the grid of this code. What it is doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *n* row x *m* column (two-dimensional) matrix is being stored in a one-dimensional array with (*n* * *m*) elements.

For example, imagine a 4 x 3 matrix. It will require a linear array with 12 elements. It has the following indexes in the array:

```
    0     1     2

0   0  |  1  |  2      #rows = 4
    -------------      #columns = 3
1   3  |  4  |  5
    -------------      array position = (row * #columns) + column
2   6  |  7  |  8
    -------------
3   9  | 10  | 11
```

Assuming that the row and column indexes start at 0, then to access the storage for the element at matrix row 3 (the fourth row), column 2 (the third column), you would use the following: (3 * 3) + 2 = 11

For row 1 (2nd row), column 1 (2nd column): (1 * 3) + 1 = 4

For row 2, column 0: (2 * 3) + 0 = 6

Hope that helps.